# Multiple list type in recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i have dynamic list question from API with recyclerview but every question have different type (Input Text,Radio Button,etc) so i need make list with diferent type in my recyclerview. i seacrh on internet also in this site i need to check list type in onCreateViewHolder and return view with different layout source but i still cant solve my problem,my result not return any error but my list is always return just first type view (input_field layout) but canot return second type view (input_selection layout)

this my adapter

```
class QuestionViewAdapter(private val listQuestion: ArrayList<Question>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionViewAdapter.InputField>() {
    private var context: Context? = null
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): InputField {
        context = viewGroup.context
        if(listQuestion[i].prodeskel_type_id == 1){
            var view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.input_field, viewGroup, false)
            return InputField(view)
        } else {
            var view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.input_selection, viewGroup, false)
            return InputField(view)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(InputFieldHolder: InputField, i: Int) {
        val question = listQuestion.get(i)

        if(question.prodeskel_type_id == 2){
            InputFieldHolder.questionText?.text = question.isi
            var rprms = InputFieldHolder.radiogroup?.layoutParams
            for (i in question.pilihan_jawabans) {
                val rdbtn = RadioButton(context)
                rdbtn.id = View.generateViewId()
                rdbtn.text = i.isi.toString()
                rprms = RadioGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                InputFieldHolder.radiogroup?.addView(rdbtn, rprms)

            }
        } else {
            InputFieldHolder.txtInput?.hint = question.isi
            if(question.getEditTextValue().toString() != "null"){
                InputFieldHolder.txtInput?.editText?.setText(question.getEditTextValue().toString())
            }


            InputFieldHolder.txtInput?.editText?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                    InputFieldHolder.txtInput?.editText?.text?.length?.let {
                        InputFieldHolder.txtInput?.editText?.setSelection(
                            it
                        )
                    }
                }

                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                                               count: Int, after: Int) {

                }

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                                           before: Int, count: Int) {
                    Log.i("Edit", InputFieldHolder.txtInput?.editText?.text.toString())
                    question.setEditTextValue(InputFieldHolder.txtInput?.editText?.text.toString())
                }
            })
        }
        InputFieldHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listQuestion.size
    }

    public fun getItem(): ArrayList<Question> {
        return listQuestion
    }

    inner class InputField internal constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        internal var txtInput: TextInputLayout? = null
        internal var radiogroup: RadioGroup? = null
        internal var questionText: TextView? = null

        init {
            txtInput = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtInputField)
            radiogroup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup)
            questionText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.questionText)
        }
     }
}
```

**UPDATE (SOLVED)**

i solved by add this function

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = listQuestion[position].prodeskel_type_id
```

and add selection condition on `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder`

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): InputField {

    if(viewType == 1){
        //view type layout1
    } else {
        //view type layout2

    }
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(InputFieldHolder: InputField, i: Int) {

    if(getItemViewType(i) == 1){
        //add text to layout1

    } else {
        //add text to layout2
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have written in the code onCreateViewHolder receives an `Int` and which is the type of view. based on that it creates `viewholders`.

But in your case the view type will be always 0. `onCreateViewHolder` receives viewType and which is returned by `getItemViewType` which you need to override.

for example

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on position
        // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
        return viewType;
    }
```

also your `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` should be depending on the viewType received as argument.

example

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): InputField {       
 if(viewType == 1){  
  ... 
 }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(InputFieldHolder: InputField, position: Int) {
  if(getViewType(position) == 1){ 
     ... 
  }
}
```

In your scenario `getViewType` will be something like this

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = listQuestion[position].prodeskel_type_id
```

Hope that helps. also I would ask you to understand how RecyclerView and its adapter works

Comment: ohh i see so i need return my type in function getItemViewType like this?    
 `override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return listQuestion[position].prodeskel_type_id
  }`

Comment: Yes. something like that. I would recommend you to add necessary null checks before accessing the values

Answer (score 1):

To use multiple item types in `RecyclerView` you need to override method `getItemViewType`. The value it returns will be placed as 2-nd parameter in `onCreateViewHolder` method (BTW, better to rename it from `i` to `viewType`). Default implementation of `getItemViewType` always returns same value, so you would never get what you want with it.

Comment: thank you for answered ,i finaly resolved what i want. i just update my question what i got